# store the 'this' object in an onclick attribute

Tags: javascript

What I ultimately want is to retrieve the innerHTML of the example script below (the html is to be put in a database). It must include the onclick events also. However in the generated HTML there is no onclick event available.

```
<html>
</head>
<script>
function test() {
    this.goodbye="goodbye!";
    this.elem=document.createElement('div');
    this.elem.style.border='1px solid #888888';
    this.elem.textContent="hello";
    this.elem.style.cursor='pointer';
    var that=this;
    this.elem.onclick=function(){that.say_goodbye();}
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(this.elem);
}

test.prototype.say_goodbye=function(blockid) {
    this.elem.textContent=this.goodbye;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>var obj = new test();</script>
<a href="javascript:alert(obj.elem.outerHTML);">get html</a>
</body>
</html>
```

the line of importance is thus:

```
this.elem.onclick=function(){that.say_goodbye();}
```

I tried to add it as attribute like:

```
this.elem.setAttribute('onclick',that.say_goodbye.bind(that));
```

But is doesn't work. When I click the link in the given code the browser alerts:

```
<div> onclick="function(){[native code]}" ..... </div>
```

In this case the HTML now has an 'onclick' event but contains '[native code]' as action.

Anyone an idea on how to make the code work?

Comment: Use `addEventListener()` rather than direct assignment to the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: @charlietfl , when you click on the link to get the html; the onlick event is not in de html code (PS, I am using FF 41.02)

Comment: the addEventListener() doesn't work neither ...

Comment: Would suggest you add some sort of data attributes that you can use to reference and build your library to work with those data attributes using unobtrusive script

Comment: Your original code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ztmpregh/ . Why exactly are you trying to change it?

Comment: @FelixKling i thought so too but OP wants to store an onclick attribute to be able to replicated after storing the html

Comment: @charlietfl: Oh I see.

Comment: @charlietfl , indeed, maybe adding it to some data-attribute is the workaround for this ...

Comment: Where it seems funky is you won't have `new test()` object when you reload the page and `onclick` relies on global namespace functions

Comment: Yeah, not sure what you are trying to do is feasible. You won't have any JS context. What's the reason for doing this? Maybe there are better ways to solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this is that attribute value is text always and you are trying to put object into it (functions are objects). This case you should rather use this.elem = that.say_goodbye.bind(that).